# Facebook provider is not authenticating users in my ionic app - using angularfire

Tags: ionic-framework, angularfire2, facebook-authentication

I am trying to implement (social & email-password) login in my ionic app..

It was working well for email-pass. When i tried adding google and facebook, i have faced a lot of problems, then a very dirty code. Now my code is working for googleauthentication, but for facebook, the app is redirecting, but returned result is {user: null}, and no thing changes.

**What is the error? Why facebook authentication is not changing this.afAuth.authState?**

Functionality is implemented in my auth.service.ts file.

A function for Facebook login is as so:

```
  loginWithFacebook() {
    this.store.dispatch(new UIActions.StartLoading());
    alert('facebook login');
    try {
      let provider = new auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
      console.log(provider);
      const credential = this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(provider);
      console.log('accomplished sign in with redirect');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        alert(error);
    }
  }
```

LoginWithGoogle (working as expected):

```
webGoogleLogin() {
  try {
      const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      console.log(provider);
      const credential = this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(provider);
      console.log('accomplished sign in with redirect');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    alert(error);
  }
}
```

I listen to auth changes in initAthListener(), which is fired on app initialization (it worked as expected for email-pass login - logout):

```
initAuthListener() {
    // this.store.dispatch(new UIActions.StartLoading());

    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      // if( user && !user.emailVerified) {
      //   this.store.dispatch(new UIActions.StopLoading());
      //   this.alertService.presentToast(this.translateService.instant("Auth.PLEASE_VALIDATE_YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS"), 3000);
      // }
      console.log(user);
      alert(user);
      if (user) {
        if(user.emailVerified) {
        this.isAuthenticated = true;
        this.store.dispatch(new AuthActions.SetAuthenticated());
        this.afStore.collection('profiles').doc<FullUserProfile>(user.uid).valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
          (profile: FullUserProfile) => {
            if (profile != null) {
                this.store.dispatch(new AuthActions.SetUserProfile(profile));
                // this.functionsGeneralDataService.initialize(profile);
                this.generalDataService.initialize(profile);
                this.store.dispatch(new UIActions.StopLoading());
                // this.router.navigate(['/groups']);
                this.goToMainPage();
            } else {
              return;
            }
          }
        );
      }
     } else {
        this.isAuthenticated = false;
        this.generalDataService.unsubscribeFromAll();
        this.store.dispatch(new AuthActions.SetUnauthenticated());
        this.store.dispatch(new AuthActions.RemoveUserProfile());
        this.store.dispatch(new GroupsActions.ClearState());

        // this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }
      this.store.dispatch(new UIActions.StopLoading());
    });
    // this.listenToRedirectResults();
  }
```

I have tried adding the following functionality at the end of inmitAuthListener(), but without solving the problem:

```
  listenToRedirectResults() {
    firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser);
        alert("THIS IS RESULT");
          this.store.dispatch(new UIActions.StartLoading());
          if (result.credential) {
            alert('result.credentials is not null');
            var token = result.user.getIdToken();
            var user = result.user;
    // if(result == null || result.user == null) {
    //   alert('result or user null');
    //   this.isAuthenticated = false;
    //   this.generalDataService.unsubscribeFromAll();
    //   this.store.dispatch(new AuthActions.SetUnauthenticated());
    //   this.store.dispatch(new AuthActions.RemoveUserProfile());
    //   this.store.dispatch(new GroupsActions.ClearState());
    // }
            alert('will get data');
            this.store.dispatch(new AuthActions.SetAuthenticated());
            this.afStore.collection('profiles').doc(user.uid).valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
              (profile: FullUserProfile) => {
                this.store.dispatch(new UIActions.StartLoading());
                this.isAuthenticated = true;
                if (profile != null) {
                    this.store.dispatch(new AuthActions.SetUserProfile(profile));
                    // this.functionsGeneralDataService.initialize(profile);
                    this.generalDataService.initialize(profile);
                    this.store.dispatch(new UIActions.StopLoading());
                    this.goToMainPage();
                } else {
                  let profile = {} as FullUserProfile;
                  profile.id = user.uid;
                  profile.email = user.email;
                  profile.name = user.displayName;
                  profile.image = { name: '', url: user.photoURL}
                  profile.type = 0;
                  profile.numberOfGroupsAllowed = 2;
                  this.afStore.collection('profiles').doc(user.uid).set(profile);
                  this.store.dispatch(new AuthActions.SetUserProfile(profile));
                    // this.functionsGeneralDataService.initialize(profile);
                    this.generalDataService.initialize(profile);
                    this.store.dispatch(new UIActions.StopLoading());
                    this.goToMainPage();
                    // this.router.navigate(['/groups']);
                }
              }
            );
            // this.router.navigate(['groups'])
          } else {
            alert('no creadential');
          }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error.message);
          this.store.dispatch(new UIActions.StopLoading());
          this.alertService.presentToast(error.message);
        });
  }
```

Notice: If the user is deleted from users of firebase console, and tried to sign in with facebook, then user is added there, but no changes in my app.

Sorry for my dirty code, i have cleaned a lot before asking the question..
Yesterday, before adding google authentication, facebook authentication was working, but logout was not.

Sorry, but i am new to the ionic framework.

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/blog/ionic-firebase-facebook-login/

Comment: Ahla wsahla hbb.

Answer (score 0):

The error: I am checking if email verified for a facebook account where email is not verified. I have restructured my code.